# Google play account, accidentally removal

Tags: google-play

I'm hosting my e-mail domain on google.
I've registered in google play (paid 25$ fee), using one of the e-mails.
Unfortunately, I've accidentally removed this e-mail account.
After restoring and loging to google play, it tells me, that I'm not registered as developer and have to pay 25$ fee again.

I used [this form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/dev_registration?rd=1) to contact google with no luck (2 days passed). Probably, google just ignored the e-mail, because I do not know "Checkout order number for Developer Account Registration". It was in deleted e-mail account.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to restore my account. 
After 4 days, google support answered my e-mail. I told them my order number, so they just sent back 25$ and I registered account again (fortunately, I didn't have any published app in account)